# Overcoming .Net 4 'security' fix that passes char codes instead of literals (jquery/mvc)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, html-encode

I'm returning some partial views via Jquery Ajax calls.  When it returns (some javascript I'm passing back, for better or worse), the single quotes - ' symbols, are returned like the below (as viewed by fiddler):

```
         xAxis: {
            categories: [&#39;Jan&#39;, &#39;Feb&#39;, &#39;Mar&#39;, &#39;Apr&#39;, &#39;May&#39;, &#39;Jun&#39;, &#39;Jul&#39;, &#39;Aug&#39;, &#39;Sep&#39;, &#39;Oct&#39;, &#39;Nov&#39;, &#39;Dec&#39;]
        },
```

So of course the javascript returned is malformed and can't be called.

Looking into this, it's apparently a ['security' update in .net v4 to avoid xss attacks](http://forums.asp.net/p/1554455/3818604.aspx).  That forum basically says that it is bad news, and suggests overriding the default HTML encoding class.  I tried this with no luck.

Any suggestions for removing this annoying functionality?

Comment: What does your action method look like that returns this JavaScript in a partial view? And what does the partial view look like, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an actual partial view you are returning, you could wrap you javascript part in a `@Html.Raw(javascript)` so it does not get encoded.

Comment: This is good, thanks for that!  I had hacked in a search/replace on the client end, but this would have meant (other than the hackyness) four bytes instead of one every time that char was sent.  Thanks!